# Trigger event when any child is focused in JS

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="line">
    <span class ="word">This </span>
        <span class ="word">is  </span>
        <span class ="word">a  </span>
        <span class ="word">line. </span>  
    </div>
    <div class="line">
    <span class ="word">This </span>
        <span class ="word">is  </span>
        <span class ="word">another  </span>
        <span class ="word">line. </span>  
    </div>
</div>

<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

The content of the parent is dynamic (it may change during runtime).

I would like to report the focus of parent or any descendant the textarea. For example, if the user click on the parent, the focus is set on the textarea.

I did the following, but it does not work:

```
let parent = document.getElementById("parent");
let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

parent.addEventListener("focus", () => { 
    textarea.focus();
})
```

Any idea is welcome. Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/6y4d931b/

Comment: 1) You need to spell `addEventListener` correctly. 2) Your div element is not currently _able_ to receive focus - you'll need to add a [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the parent DIV focusable:

```
<div id="parent" tabindex="-1">
```

Use `tabindex="-1"` for the click only and `tabindex="0"` if you want to get the event when you navigate with a keyboard.

Also please use embedded code snippets here, that way you can get them right, without typos for example.

```js
let parent = document.getElementById("parent");
let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

parent.addEventListener("focus", () => { // you have a type here, should be addEventListener
    console.log ("focus");
    textarea.focus();
});
```

```html
<div id="parent" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="line">
    <span class ="word">This </span>
        <span class ="word">is  </span>
        <span class ="word">a  </span>
        <span class ="word">line. </span>  
    </div>
    <div class="line">
    <span class ="word">This </span>
        <span class ="word">is  </span>   
        <span class ="word">another  </span>
        <span class ="word">line. </span>  
    </div>
</div>

<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```